# Isolated teenage boy evading alien-controlled mechanical bots while seeking food and human contact

Tags: story-identification, books, alien-invasion

A young teenage boy, whose family is recently deceased, is now living alone in a secluded forest cabin.  He primitively survives using a bow and arrow for food.  He was raised to never leave the safety of the forest.

He decides he must seek what is beyond the forest and make contact with other humans. He leaves the forest periodically scouting and discovers an alien invasion has taken place.  He manages to evade capture or death by alien-controlled machines that roam the fields and countryside.  He seeks food while traversing farm fields and small towns attempting to learn what has happened to other humans.

He finally discovers a group of humans who have been captured/corralled/controlled by the aliens.  I seem to recall he makes contact with a human female from the captured group of humans.

That is all I can recall.  I have not been successful in finding this book to finish the story.  First read 20+ years ago.